# Task Schedule R scripts to run every minute

Tags: r, scheduled-tasks

I would like to run a script every minute and this script plots me the current positions.

I am using taskscheduleR to run the script and my code looks like this:

```
taskscheduler_create(taskname = "myfancyscript_5min", rscript = Japanscript,
                     schedule = "MINUTE", starttime = "11:15", modifier = 1)
```

This returns me an error:

```
[1] "ERROR: Incorrect Start Date."
attr(,"status")
[1] 16389

Warning message:
In system(cmd, intern = TRUE) :
  running command 'schtasks /Create /TN "JapanRisk" /TR "cmd /c C:/Users/CLAKeSH~1/DOCUME~1/R-35~1.1/bin/Rscript.exe \"//Lakesh/Codes/R/Japan_Live_monitor_v1.R\"  >> \"//Lakesh/Codes/R/Japan_Live_monitor_v1.log\" 2>&1" /SC MINUTE /MO 5 /ST 12:55 /SD "23/10/2018" ' had status 16389
```

Not sure how to fix it. I dont see any date parameter being passed to the function.

I also need to run the scripts so that the plots are visible. How do i do that as well?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure which version of R or taskscheduleR package you are using but you can pass `startdate` within the function.

As per `?taskscheduler_create`, you can do

```
taskscheduler_create(taskname = "myfancyscript_5min", rscript = Japanscript,
                     schedule = "MINUTE", starttime = "11:15", startdate = format(Sys.Date(), "%d/%m/%Y"))
```

Comment: can you provide sessionInfo()

Comment: any idea on this?

Comment: Scheduling on `format(Sys.Date(), "%d/%m/%Y")` is something different than scheduling on `format(Sys.Date(), "%m/%d/%Y")`

Comment: Which R version and  `taskscheduleR` are you using? In `R3.5.0` and `taskscheduleR_1.1` it seems to work. Maybe try passing yesterday's date e.g. `startdate = format(as.Date("2018-10-23"), "%d/%m/%Y")`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the taskscheduleR addin existed when you asked the question but to answer this question in today's version of RStudio, it's now an Addin for RStudio. If you do not see it, install these packages:

```
install.packages('miniUI')
install.packages('shiny')
install.packages("taskscheduleR")
```

Once you have it opened, add the following parameters in:

Additional arguments to RScript:

```
startdate = format(Sys.Date(), "%m/%d/%Y")
```

Change Date format of your locale:
`%m/%d/%Y`

(note this is the way your machine's clock is formatted!)

Answer (score 0):

Change Date format of your locale:
%m/%d/%Y
(note this is the way your machine's clock is formatted!)

[Check here](https://github.com/bnosac/taskscheduleR/issues/49#issuecomment-533842325)